# Excel Pulling Text within Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a cell that contain this text string.  I was wondering if I can pull the text between from and upon. So it captures AAA (being varying degree of length)

```
life insurance policy #111 111 111 for the amount of $500,000.00 from AAA upon the life of xxx
```

So far I only managed this:
     =MID(STP_Data!D71,FIND("from",STP_Data!D71), 42)

But if the text length changes it wouldn't capture it.  Also how would I not capture from within my formula.  Since my currently formula will include 'from' when it is pulled.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work?

`=Trim(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("from",A1),SEARCH("upon",A1)-SEARCH("from",A1)),"from",""))`

Edit: Added `TRIM()` per Scott's suggestion.

Comment: I would wrap it in TRIM() right now you are returning the spaces on both sides.

Comment: Also without the SUBSTITUTE(): `=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("from",A1)+4,SEARCH("upon",A1)-SEARCH("from",A1)-4))` we just need to do the math.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ahhh, it's the `+4` and then `-4`  that I was missing. I kept just trying one or the other and was getting `from AAA` or `AAA upon`. Thanks for that :D

Comment: the Search returns the where the word starts so we need to add that length to the return to get to the back of the word, then when subtracting since A-(B+C) is the same as A-B-C, I shorthanded it and left off the two `()`  it could have been `SEARCH("upon",A1)-(SEARCH("f‌​rom",A1)+4)`  But again I saved two keystrokes. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - Good call!  ...to be super annoying about not using magic numbers, I was even doing `len("upon")` haha, but that's pretty unnecessary for this, and just adds keystrokes.